# Could someone walk me through this pde?

Tags: calculus, limits, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

$$\frac{\partial^2 y} {\partial x^2}
  = \lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \frac {1} {\Delta x}
                          \left(\frac{\partial y} {\partial x}_x - \frac{\partial y} {\partial x}_{x+ \Delta x}\right)$$

Could anyone explain to me why this is?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what the symbol
$$
\frac{\partial y} {\partial x}_x
$$
refers to.

What you likely intended is that
$$
\frac{\partial^2 y}{\partial x^2}
 = \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left[ \frac{\partial y}{\partial x} \right]
 = \lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \frac{\left.\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}\right|_{x+\Delta_x}
                              - \left.\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}\right|_x}{\Delta x}
$$

**EDIT** Now I understood that you wanted someone to explain why that is. Well, recall that if $f$ is a differentiable function, then
$$
f'(x) = \lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \frac{f(x+\Delta x) - f(x)}{\Delta x}.
$$

Note that if you are looking for a 2nd derivative, you can say that
$$
f''(x) = \frac{df'(x)}{dx} = \lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \frac{f'(x+\Delta x) - f'(x)}{\Delta x}.
$$

Now translate that last formula to the language of partial derivatives, and you are done.

Comment: Yes, sorry didn't know how to correctly format. Thank's for the edit

Comment: @FraserPrice please see the edit.

Comment: @FraserPrice no problem, glad to be of help